# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)}$

Tags: calculus

Please see below:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)}= (\frac{1}{2}\ln(x+1)+\frac{1}{2}\ln(x+3) - \ln(x+2)$$

I do not have problem evaluating the above integral integral itself, however I have problem calculating its limits. Please notice depending whether you simplify the answer according to the logarithm rukes you can evalaute the limit which would give you as x approaches infinity which becomes equalt to "Zero"or "Infinity" or "$\ln(2)$"!

---Edit --
Ok even more explanation

$\lim_{x\to \infty}(\frac{1}{2}\ln(x+1)+\frac{1}{2}\ln(x+3) - \ln(x+2))= 0$ check with wolfram as well
so why the actual answer evaluates to $\ln(2)$

Comment: I just edited and elaborated more on the bottom line issue.

Comment: To evaluate at infinity, combine the logarithms, interchange the logarithm and limit and use L'Hospital's

Comment: can someone explain the -1 there. it is a legit question.

Comment: @Gaffney: please elaborate you solution of  L'Hospital's in this context! the above integral does not lead to indeterminate limit. Please enlighten me.

Comment: The first equation is a definite integral and needs no +C term at the end.

Comment: @JohnJPershing: Thanks. Any help to my problem.

Comment: @arashaga The above integral *does* lead to an indeterminate limit.  You yourself identified this issue in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The indefinite integral according to Wolfram is $${1\over 2}\ln\left(\frac{(x+1)(x+3)}{(x+2)^2}\right)$$ At $x=0$ this is $1/2 \ln{(3/4)}$. At $x=\infty$ this is $0$ because the expression inside the log approaches one. Therefore the answer is $$-{1\over 2}\ln\left({3\over 4}\right)$$

Comment: sorry for my ignorance how the denominator was squared?

Comment: using the identity $a\ln b=\ln(b^a)$.